# Dictionary duplicate values insert

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I wanted to add student name and followed by their marks(3 subject marks) to a dictionary.

The input look like this

```
2
student1 56 89 78
student2 89 63 89
```

1st line represent n which is the number of student

2nd line represent student name followed by their marks

So i used this code to insert it to the dictionary.

```
n = int(input())
my_dict = {}
my_list = []
average = 0
for i in range(n):
    my_list.append(input().split(' '))
    my_dict[my_list[i][0]] = {my_list[i][k] for k in range(1, 4)}
```

I have faced problem when I try to enter same marks for 2 subjects.

Comment: im going to assume you want something along the lines of : `{student: [scores], ...}` right?

Comment: Yes! that's what i want.

Comment: Can you give an example of your problematic input and explain what exactly it means *I have faced problem*?

Comment: As in the example `student2 89 63 89` , when the student have same marks for 2 subjects , my code only takes the unique values. that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a simple `dictionary comprehension` for this.

```
#get number of entries
n=int(input())

#get some nested lists if the data by splitting each input.
inputs = [input("enter student data: ").split() for i in range(n)]

#using a dictionary comprehension to make the first list value the key and the rest values of a list (using map to convert to integer for easy use)
data = {i[0] : list(map(int, i[1:])) for i in inputs}

print(data)
```

```
2 #input is 2
enter student data: iron 100 95 90 #input is iron 100 95 90
enter student data: key 60 70 60 #input is key 60 70 60
{'iron': [100, 95, 90], 'key': [60, 70, 60]} #output
```

and if you use duplicates:

```
2
enter student data: iron 10 20 30
enter student data: iron 10 20 30
{'iron': [10, 20, 30]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that set can not have duplicate values.
This code:

```
{my_list[i][k] for k in range(1,4)}
```

is creating a dictionary with the set as its value thus not allowing duplicates.

Use this:

```
my_dict = dict()
n = int(input())

for _ in range(n):
    temp = input().split()
    student = temp[0]
    marks = temp[1:]
    marks = list(map(int, marks)) # add this if you want the marks to be int
    my_dict[student] = marks
```